# Systematic Review - Intervention and Control

Tags: regression

In most of the systematic reviews, there is a PICO question with the intervention and comparator/control of interest. After the search strategy, the papers found usually have the same intervention and control. My question is: If my intervention and comparator of interest is not directly compared head-on in any paper, nor could I use a network meta-analysis as there is no common comparator. Instead, the intervention and comparator that I am interested in is only a procedure that is part of the research paper.

E.g. There is a step-wise management protocol to treat a subset of patients, and research papers focus on the last step (comparing different interventions). However, in the research papers, there are variations in whether the 2nd step of the protocol should be done earlier or later. And I want to ingestigate the effectiveness of making this 2nd step earlier in the management protocol. I understand that the data that I get would only be observational in nature and hard to prove its causality as the data is not specifically focused on that, but is it sufficient in the systematic review to just do so?

In addition, to adjust for the confounding factors (including the main intervention/ control of the reseearch papers), do I use multiple linear regression? Or should I use other sorts of statistical package? Or is sensitivity analysis okay?

Comment: Welcome to the site! How many papers are you including in your analysis? What do the data look like when you compare outcome to the factors you think might be relevant? (I'm just talking about exploratory analysis, without any attempt at choosing an explicit model.)